# Stagger animation in a random order with TweenMax

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gsap

I'm trying to create a staggerTo() animation with TweenMax that affects elements in a random order, meaning I don't want the actual animation to be random but its order.

For that I take all the elements I want to animate and shuffle using this function:

```
$.fn.shuffle = function() {

    var allElems = this.get(),
        getRandom = function(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        },
        shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
            var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                allElems.splice(random, 1);
                return randEl;
        });

    return $(shuffled);

};

var elements = $('.animate').shuffle();
```

I then lunch the staggerTo animation:

```
TweenMax.staggerTo(elements, 0.1, {y: 100, ease: Quad.easeInOut}, 0.1);
```

But of course, I then realized I had it all wrong, as TweenMax wasn't animating the actual DOM elements but rather its virtual clones.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed from here.

Could anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I am probably failing to understand your scenario but it seems that at the core of it, I think your problem is more about randomizing an array of jQuery elements. Have you taken a look at [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/)?

1. Convert your elements to array like so: `var elements=$('.animate').toArray();`.
2. Shuffle this array using [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/shuffle-array/) technique: `elements.sort(function(){return 0.5-Math.random()});`. Thanks to CSS-Tricks.com.
3. Then feed this new array to the `staggerTo` call: `TweenMax.staggerTo(elements, 0.1, {y: 100, ease: Quad.easeInOut}, 0.1);` i.e. what you already have.
4. Quick jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/kyuz2m8c/2/).

Please note that there are many [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/3344111) when it comes to shuffling arrays.